# Tips, Tricks, Shortcuts for using EnigmaCurry's Emacs configuration

Tags: python, emacs, emacs23

I just stated using emacs and wanted to find a good configuration for python programming.
I **choose** the [EnigmaCurry](http://github.com/EnigmaCurry/emacs) emacs **configuration** which is very extensive. There are a lot of ".el" files.

The problem with this configuration is the **lack of documentation** on how to use the various tools. Without knowledge of emacs-lisp I feel a little in the dark as to the **full capability** of this configuration.

So if anyone has **Tips, Tricks, or Shortcuts** in **EnigmaCurry**'s configuration I would love to hear them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

People generally don't document their personal configuration that much, especially because they are generally aware what is what. The [Emacs Starter Kit](http://github.com/technomancy/emacs-starter-kit) is targeting newbie Emacs users and has better documentation than average.

It might seem a bit self-promoting, but I encourage you to take a look at [my personal config](https://github.com/bbatsov/emacs-prelude) as well, since I happen to monitor a lot of Emacs channels and use a lot of innovative stuff. My configuration is also highly modular and has more comments than most.

That said I'd recommend you if find something in anyone's config you can't understand to just look up the library to which the configuration relates in [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org) and drop by in #emacs irc channel on freenode and ask for help. The community there is great!

Comment: I changed the link since it was 404ing, it seems that most of your config is on Emacs Prelude now so I linked there. Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 4):

While I'm honored that you chose my emacs config to start with, I have to second Bozhidar's answer. The [Emacs Starter Kit](http://github.com/technomancy/emacs-starter-kit) is a good place to start for beginners. I personally think that my config is well suited to the way I like to do things, especially for Python development, but it's really pretty crufty and probably unapproachable to other people.

I've blogged about my Emacs config [quite a bit](http://enigmacurry.com/category/emacs/), but I've learned that Emacs configuration is such a personal thing that if I wanted to turn it into something that was turn-key for everyone else I'd have to spend a lot more time on it to make it user-friendly. Honestly, right now I'm a lot more focused on developing things with Emacs, rather then developing Emacs itself.

So, my suggestion is to start with [Emacs Starter kit](http://github.com/technomancy/emacs-starter-kit), and then read my config to gain new ideas to add to your own.